# Django-admin , going to external site with my variables on URL

Tags: django, url, parameters, django-templates

I have a model and i want to go to a external website with my variables in the url. For example: "www.example.com\ {% object.field %}.com

**My model**

```html
class Intervencao(models.Model):
    freguesia = models.ForeignKey(Freguesia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Freguesia")
    rua = models.ForeignKey(Rua, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Rua")
```

**My view**

```html
from daa.intervencao.models import Intervencao

def home(request):
    var = Intervencao.object.all()
    context = {
        'key' : var
            }
    return render(request, 'templates/admin/daa/change_form_object_tools.html', context)
```

**My url**

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls, name ='home'),
    ]
```

I'm changing my change_form_object_tools.html and add a extra li to do something like this:

```html
<li>
    <a href="www.example.com/{{ key.field }}" target="_blank">Encontrar no SIG</a>
</li>
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to pass the model.field as a dict into the template from the views.py and then you put it on the href like this {{ model.field }}
In your template you loop through the Key list like that 
{% for k in  key %}
 li to do something like this:

Encontrar no SIG

{%  endfor %}

```
You can use the other field "rua" if you want
```

Comment: I already tried to do this, by the way I even edited the question to see if I did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'd extend @farhani's answer here

```
views.py


from yourappname.models import Intervencao


def home(request):


var = Intervencao.object.all()


context = {
     'key' : var
          }


return render(request, 'templates/change_form_object_tools.html', context)
```

Make sure you pass this to a root url

```
root urls.py


from yourappname.views import home


urlpatterns = [


path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', home,),


......
]
```

Jump to the templates now

```
<li>
    <a href="www.example.com\{{ key.field }}.com">Example</a>
</li>
```

Hope that answer's your question.
Cheers

Comment: I already tried to do this, by the way I even edited the question to see if I did something wrong

Comment: you have to have a template showing to that specific link which you are probably passing. <a href="www.example.com\{{ key.field }}.com">Example</a> Make sure that the **key.field** has a templete to this. Otherwise it'll throw an error

Comment: Can you be more specific with the issues?

Comment: When I click the button to redirect me to a external website, he simply returns me to my app saying he didn't find any id and don't go to my external website